# Cobertura, coverage over multiple jar-files

Tags: java, maven, tdd, code-coverage, cobertura

Is there a way to get Cobertura to gather test-coverage over several .jar-files. The problem I have is that after a refactoring of classes that where covered, being in the same .jar, are no longer being reported as covered (since they now are in a separate .jar).

So, the question, for a ear-project, containing several source-projects (.jar), is there a way to get the actual coverage for the ear-project instead of a sum of of .jar-coverages.

Basically, the tests reflects behaviour, not code-structure. Since we only changed structure, the behaviour isn't changed. Therefore the tests should not need to change and since the tests are not changed then the coverage should not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've 2 good options:

1) Have your cobertura maven plugin in a single (parent) pom and set the [aggregate property](http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/cobertura-mojo.html#aggregate) to true, which should overlay your cobertura reports on top of each other. [See this blog post](http://blog.the-future-group.com/2014/01/28/maven-aggregate-reports-multi-module-projects/) as an example.

2) If you only care about the report, use a report aggregating tool such as [Sonar](http://www.sonarqube.org/) to not only give you aggregated reports across the project, but a whole host of extra metrics and useful info.

Answer (score 0):

I have red that if you organized your project in a Maven multi-module project (one module for each jar) you should be able [to merge the cobertura reports in one report](http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/instrumentingDeploymentArtifact.html), but I have never tryed what written at that page.